# How bootstrap decide what should be made?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

I have `cdk` project which still somehow blackbox to me. So, I am analyzing it.

This project has a few stacks like `NetworkStack`,`StoreStack`,`DeployStack`

with this command.

```
`cdk bootstrap --toolkit-stack-name my-dev-cdk`
```

It makes one `AWS::SSM::Parameter`, one `AWS::ECR::Repository` a few roles, policies and one `AWS::S3::Bucket`

OK, it's cool.

However, where can I find what should be made by `bootstrap`?

or How bootstrap decide what should be made?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrapping does not depend on the stacks you're deploying, it's the same for everyone by default. You can specify your own template, but that's for advanced usage. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/bootstrapping.html) lays out the purposes of bootstrapping pretty clearly:

> Deploying AWS CDK apps into an AWS environment (a combination of an
> AWS account and region) may require that you provision resources the
> AWS CDK needs to perform the deployment. These resources include an
> Amazon S3 bucket for storing files and IAM roles that grant
> permissions needed to perform deployments. The process of provisioning
> these initial resources is called bootstrapping.