# How to get the api gateway with lambda access log?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

I have api gateway with lambda

I make the gateway simply with this.

```
const lambdaGw = new apigw.LambdaRestApi(this, "LambdaEndpoint", {
  restApiName:`vr-${targetEnv}-lambda-endpoint`,

  handler: myLambda,
});
```

It makes the api gateway.

I go to the console and choose one gateway and went to setting, but can't find the log setting.

So, I guess , I need to do something in advance to gether the access log?.

then I checked the `[LambdaRestApi document][1]`

However I could't find the any information about logs.

What I want to do is checking the logs and restrict the access from a certain domain.

Comment: If you are trying to verify the access log settings, they are set in the Stage details which falls under deployOptions in LambdaRestApi. The resource policy and restrictions can be set by a policyDocument using policy on the LambdaRestapi.  https://gist.github.com/quixoticmonk/e90312b01e18be2a13825eda23dbfe25

Comment: Please make sure to accept answers to the previous questions besides posting new ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70881161/how-to-add-an-event-notification-to-an-imported-bucket/70881986#70881986 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70835443/how-bootstrap-decide-what-should-be-made/70837811#70837811

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Access logs can be enabled via the [`deployOptions` prop](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.LambdaRestApi.html#deployoptions), which takes [`StageOptions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.StageOptions.html).

Specify the [`accessLogDestination`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_apigateway.StageOptions.html#accesslogdestination) to enable access logs.

Comment: I make the `S3` and put long in s3 bucket,     `const lb = new elb.ApplicationLoadBalancer(....);` `lb.logAccessLogs(s3forlog);`